# PHP limit number of game cards avalaible

Tags: javascript, php, probability

I'm working on a scratch card game for a website. The game is simple, win or lose.

I found this code in php for the game, it's working great :

```
function winningChance(int $percentage): string
{
if ($percentage < 0 || $percentage > 100) {
    throw new \Exception('Invalid percentage');
}
return rand(1, 100) <= $percentage ? 'won' : 'lost';
}
echo "You've " . winningChance(1) . '!';
```

But I have a problem, I need to limit the number of playing cards and generate randomly just one time a winning card and don't know how to do that.

For exemple :

I limit the game to 150 playing cards, so I have 150 players, 149 losers, 1 winner ?

How can i do that in php ? Can someone help me ?

Thank you !

Comment: Not nearly as easy. You need some sort of persistence that will keep the record of how many cards remaining before the winner. It can be a text file, or a database, but you need to have something that will store the data between requests, and be shared between different clients (so not SESSION).

Comment: use an array of cards, you can use the key as the face of the card, mark them with 0's or 1 with a 1, then you remove cards as you need, you can save them by simply putting them in a text file using `file_put_contents('cards.php', '<?php return '.var_export($cards, true).';')`  You can load the cards with a simple `$cards = include 'cards.php'; ` etc.  use `array_suffle` to randomize and `array_pop` to "deal" a card.

Comment: Do your server have a database setup? Do you know how to connect to a database?

Comment: Yes it's a wordpress, I know how to create a custom table and how to connect to a database

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need something like this:

```php
<?php

/**
 * Gets a random result for a given min-max pair and
 * remember the result until the provided database is
 * removed / truncated.
 *
 * @param PDO $db
 *   Database connected to store result.
 * @param int $min
 *   Minimum integer for the result.
 * @param int $max
 *   Maximum integer for the result.
 */
function remember_or_new_result(PDO $db, int $min, int $max):int {
  // create and prepare a database file to store past results.
  $db->query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS result (card INT PRIMARY KEY, min INT, max, INT)');

  // search existing result
  $search = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, card FROM result WHERE min=:min AND max=:max');
  if ($search && $search->execute([':min' => $min, ':max' => $max])) {
    $result = $search->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    if ($result->count > 0) return $result->card; // return past result
  }

  // randomize and remember the result.
  $rand = rand($min, $max);
  $insert = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO result (min, max, card) VALUES (:min, :max, :card)');
  $insert->execute([
    ':min' => $min,
    ':max' => $max,
    ':card' => $rand,
  ]);

  return $rand;
}

// connect to an SQLite database. Require php-sqlite3 installed.
// or simply change the database connection string.
$db = new PDO('sqlite:local.db');
echo ($your_card == remember_or_new_result($db, 1, 150)) ? 'win' : 'lost';
```